# “signal out of range” when starting grub after Natty server installation

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I get “signal out of range” displayed on screen after boot up from fresh Ubuntu installation, if flashes grup in corner for half a sec then it goes to “No Input Signal”, anyone got a clue how to get the grub to load in diffrent resolution with out have access to the file system?

if not i guess my only option is to boot from the cd and edit som files to get grub to load in diffrent resolution?

as it is now i cant get access to grub menu, and i cant get access to login screen, all will give me “No Input Signal”, anyone worked around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could let the system come up and then access one of the text VTY's to make configuration changes.  Wait until the system has finished booting and use `CTRL`-`ALT`-`F1` to access the text console.

If that still leaves your monitor showing `No Input` or similar, your only real option will be to boot from a LiveCD, mount the filesystem(s) on your machine and make the necessary configuration changes.